# CloudWatch Event Rule: Disable itself

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a cloudwatch event-rule which runs a lambda-function and is configured f.e. like `cron(0/2 21-22 15 4 ? 2020)`.
Inside the lambda function it checks on something. If that condition is fulfilled, I want to disable the rule. I cannot do it via

```
new CloudWatchEvents().disableRule({Name: 'MyRule'})
```

because of concurrency. Is there any other way to achieve it comfortably?

Comment: How about putting a message in sqs queue?

Comment: thank you for this hint. I never checked out sqs - will do now.

Comment: @Kane work great - thank you!